# copy a date object from a user entered date

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to put together a mostly automated form.  I have the get current date fine but I am having problems collecting information from a user enter date to place it in another part of the form as well + 1 year.  I.E. D.O.B = 08/06/2016 farther down the form expires 08/06/2017. I can make the current date enter automatically but when i try and get the date entered from the user nothing fills the lower date.  I tried getting the date using document.getElementById('dob')

```
function datePone()
{
    var date = new Date();

    var day = date.getDate(document.getElementById('dob'))
    var month = date.getMonth(document.getElementById('dob')) + 1;
    var year = date.getFullYear(document.getElementById('dob')) + 1;

    if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
    if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;

    var oneYear = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;       
    document.getElementById("dateOneYear").value = oneYear;

}
```

I've tried using set date or making a new var using document.getElementById('dob') but nothing i have tried has worked so far.

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: function datePone()
{
 var date = new Date();
 
 
 
 var day = date.getDate(docmument.getElementbyID('dob'))
 var month = date.getMonth(docmument.getElementbyID('dob')) + 1;
 var year = date.getFullYear(docmument.getElementbyID('dob')) + 1;

 if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
 if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;

 var oneYear = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;       
 document.getElementById("dateOneYear").value = oneYear;
    
}
</script>

Comment: Add it in your question .

Comment: Your dob is a TextBox?? Or using datepicker

Comment: document.getElementById('dob').value should work while fetching the user's date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since "dob" is an input field, to the get the entered data you need to use value property, so try

```
document.getElementById('dob').value
```

Also I suggest using momentjs library to manipulate with dates.

Comment: Thank you.  don't know why i didn't think of that.  I had to play around with it a bit more but that did the trick.

Comment: Glad it helped, can you please mark my answer in this case, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where you have:

```
var day = date.getDate(document.getElementById('dob'))
```

the *getDate* method does not take any arguments, so they are ignored and the above is equivalent to:

```
var day = date.getDate()
```

You don't specify what format you're using for the string, "08/06/2016" is ambiguous. Does it represent 8 June or August 6?

You should not use the Date constructor or Date.parse to parse date strings, write your own small function or use a library. Also, adding one year to a date like 29 Feb 2016 will end up on 1 March 2017, so you need to apply a rule to accept that or change it to 28 Feb 2017.

Anyhow, assuming the input is in the format dd/mm/yyyy and you want the output date in the format yyyy-mm-dd, you can use a library or small functions like the following:

```js
// Parse string in d/m/y format
// If invalid, return invalid Date
function parseDMY(s){
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1]? d : new Date(NaN);
}

// Return date string in yyyy-mm-dd format
function toISODate(d) {
  return d.getFullYear() + '-' +
    ('0' + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
    ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2);
}

// Parse string to Date
var d = parseDMY('06/08/2016');
// Add one year
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 1);

console.log(toISODate(d));
```

Using a library like fecha.js, you'd parse the string using:

```
var d = fecha.parse('06/08/2016','DD/MM/YYYY');
```

and format the output:

```
fecha.format(d, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```